# Using custom rewrite rules on Wordpress multisite htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a couple of custom rewrite rules to the htaccess file on our Wordpress multisite setup but no matter where I put them they aren't having any effect - I've checked the rule itself with a couple of test urls on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and they work as intended but when put into the htaccess file nothing is happening. Is this because of the way the Wordpress rewrite function works?

Here is the content of my htaccess file…

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# Redirect Test subscription page - needed for subscription ad.
Redirect 301 /subscriptions/test/ /subscriptions/product-category/test/
Redirect 301 /subscriptions/test /subscriptions/product-category/test/

# Redirect the Test 2 stuff as no longer selling them
Redirect 301 /subscriptions/product-category/test2/ /subscriptions/
```

The pages I want to redirect are…

```
http://www.example.com/tigers-strengthen-its-position-in-market/testing1/
http://www.example.com/tigers-strengthen-its-position-in-market/testing2/
http://www.example.com/tigers-strengthen-its-position-in-market/testing2/
```

and I want to redirect them to…

```
http://www.example.com/news/
```

My redirect rule is…

```
RewriteRule ^tiger-bills-strengthens-position(.*) /news/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by using regex alteration in RewriteCond. Working code is…

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (tigers\-strengthen|testing1|testing2) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (tigers\-strengthen|testing1|testing2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]
```